# Is it possible to send Map entrySet's keys and values from java program as the arguments to a shell script?

Tags: java, shell, dictionary, key

I am trying to do something like this:

```
String[] cmdArray = new String[{"/Users/my/path/to/test.sh", mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue()};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```

where mapEntry.getKey and mapEntry.getValue() are sent as the shell script's variable values.
Is it possible to do it this way or is there other way of sending map's keys and values as arguments to a shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as a one-liner, but fairly simple with a loop.  You might find it easier to use a collection and then convert that collection to an array.  Something like:

```
List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
cmdList.add("/Users/my/path/to/test.sh");
for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
    cmdList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
    cmdList.add(entry.getValue().toString());
}
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]));
```